# d3.js - update a GeoJSON element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a map in which I first define state outlines with paths defined by a GeoJSON file, as well as a little bit of extra info, like state name. After loading, I'd like to fill the states and populate a tooltip based on data from a csv, using some buttons and checkboxes (year, different subsets of data).

I find that when I call .data() on the state objects a second time, using the csv rather than the json file, the paths disappear since they only exist in json. Is there a way I can only update certain variables? Is there a better way to bind the state objects to dynamic data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have generally approached this, and the way the code is set up in the [choropleth map example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/choropleth.html), is to load the two files separately, and then join the data on feature id when you need it. This is easiest if you load the files in sequence, like this:

```
// make a container
var counties = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "counties");

// load the data you're showing
d3.json("unemployment.json", function(data) {
  // load the geo data (you could reverse the order here)
  d3.json("us-counties.json", function(json) {
    // make the map
    counties.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", path);
    // now join the data, maybe in a separate function
    update(data)
  });
});
```

In your `update()` function, you take the data and apply operations (colors, etc) to the map based on id:

```
update(data) {
    // look at the loaded counties
    counties.selectAll("path")
      // update colors based on data
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        // get the id from the joined GeoJSON
        var countyId = d.id;
        // get the data point. This assumes your data is an object; if your data is
        // a CSV, you'll need to convert it to an object keyed to the id
        var datum = data[countyId];
        // now calculate your color
        return myColorScale(datum);
      });
}
```

Comment: nrabinowitz's solution works like a charm. Just be aware that you are referencing the unique feature id of the GeoJSON object, not a property. - The number of array elements and GeoJSON objects must be exactly the same or you will see a console error. - The array postion must match the id to display the right content with the right map element. - If you sort the array, data may not match the correct map element.

Comment: I am trying to implement this. The fill does not show unless the data is reentered, in my finding. Can you confirm?